# Setting an admin page using sessions and type in sql database?

Tags: php, sql

I have created a website with a functioning login system and in my database in the users table there is a column names type with either standard or admin. I have created a page for the admin only to edit products etc however i'm stuck on how to set it so only the 'admin' can view the page instead of just anyone that is logged in. Heres what I have so far?

admin.php

```
 <?session_start(); ?>  
 <?php
 include 'login.php'; // this includes all my login form and login action
 include 'connection.php'; // this is my database connection
 $query1 = "SELECT type FROM users";
 $result = mysqli_query($query1); 
 $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $_SESSION['usertype'] = $user['usertype'];        

 if($_SESSION['type'] = 'admin'){
//admin content here
 {
<?php
if ($_SESSION['type']) = 'standard')
{
echo 'you must be an admin to see this page';
}
?>
```

loginaction.php

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include'connection.php';

 $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
 $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
 $password=md5($_POST["password"]);
 if (empty($email) or empty($password)) {
 header("Location: homepage.php?form=invalid");   //Redirection information
 exit;
 }

 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
 echo "E-mail is not valid";
 header("Location: homepage.php?email=invalid");
 exit;
 }
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email' AND password = '$password' ";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in query: $query. " .      mysqli_error());

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {//Then we have a successful login
$_SESSION["authenticatedUserEmail"] = $email;
$_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
$_SESSION["password"] = $row['password'];
header("Location: homepage.php");
} else {//Login was unsuccessful
echo "User does not exist";
header("Location: login.php?user=invalid");
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using comaprisons instead setting values for variables in the conditions where you check for the user type.

```
if($_SESSION['type'] ='admin'){ `should be` if($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin'){
```

```js
<? session_start(); ?>
<? php
include 'login.php'; // this includes all my login form and login action
include 'connection.php'; // this is my database connection
$query1 = "SELECT type FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($query1);
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['usertype'] = $user['usertype'];

if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin') {
  //admin content here
}

if ($_SESSION['type']) == 'standard') {
  echo 'you must be an admin to see this page';
} ?>
```

There are other errors in the code such as not putting the curly braces to end the statements correctly. This code should work, however it is a very unsafe code as anyone with sql injection and good programming knowledge will "tear" your website apart and worse, they steal and manipulate your data.

You should use mysql_real_escape_string() to make the input from users sql injection proof to fairly high extent.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems seems in your code too, along with the problem mentioned by @Vish in the answers:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query1);
```

Expected a [connection link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) as first argument.

Again:

you are trying to fetch `type` from the `user table`. But using `usertype` in `mysqli_fetch_array`. Seems it is incorrect. And the `$_SESSION['type']` variable is really `$_SESSION['usertype']` ?

A modified code.

```
 $query1 = "SELECT type FROM users";
 $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query1); 
 $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $_SESSION['usertype'] = $user['type'];        

 if($_SESSION['usertype'] == 'admin')
 {

  //admin content here
 } 
 elseif ($_SESSION['usertype']) == 'standard')
 {
   echo 'you must be an admin to see this page';
 }
```

P.S: Not sure it will solve your problem